# How to use FilePathResult.WriteFile?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

### Background

I have a secured folder containing secret report files (in pdf format). Each file corresponds to a single user.

My site is developed using Asp.net MVC 3 Razor.

When a user navigate to `http://mydomain.com/UserProfile/Report`, it invokes the GET-handling action method `Report` and return a view with a submit button `Download Report`.

When the user click the button, it invokes the POST-handling action method. Verification will be done in this action method. When the verification is successfully passed, the action method returns the requested file.

### Question

Could you give me an example how to implement the POST-handling action method?

Here is the skeleton:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Report(/*any parameter I don't know*/)
{
    if(!IsAuthenticated())
        return RedirectToActionLink("SomeActionMethod","SomeController");
    else
    {
       // what should I do here?
       // Asssume my secret folder is d:\mydomain.com\secret and the public folder is d:\mydomain.com\httpdoc
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) method to return a [FileContentResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filecontentresult%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

```
[HttpPost]
public FileContentResult Report()
{
  if(!IsAuthenticated())
    return RedirectToActionLink("SomeActionMethod","SomeController");
  else
  {
    string path = @"d:\mydomain.com\secret\" + fileName;
    return File(path, "application/pdf"); ////
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can return a file back to the client:

```
public FileContentResult Report(/*any parameter I don't know*/)
{
    if(!IsAuthenticated())
        return RedirectToActionLink("SomeActionMethod","SomeController");
    else
    {
        // Read the file from your location into a byte array named content
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        return new FileContentResult(content, "application/pdf");

    }
}
```